# Changing Active Directory user password

Tags: language-agnostic, active-directory

How can I change an Active Directory user password using Directory Services without knowing old password?

Comment: C# or Java? *Usually* people pick one or the other for a project.

Comment: i picked both because people in both languages may done this.anyway it's just the logic i want.coding in both languages will be similar.

Comment: I retagged with the 'language-agnostic' tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably searching the `SetPassword` method, which you should invoke on a `DirectoryEntry` object.

Check the "Reset a User's Password" example here: [Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx).

**EDIT**:
If you are having problems with the directory entry being null, you are probably passing a wrong path. The path should be something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=johndoe,CN=Users,DC=acme,DC=com");
```

Comment: i used that method but its not working.When i got the search result,it shows null while debugging.But the user is there in AD

Comment: @Abhimanyu: The solution by Paolo should be correct. Can you explain what did you mean by "it shows null", what is null when you were debugging? Some code on what you are doing now would help.

Comment: @Amry: After executing this line of code(DirectoryEntry uEntry = new DirectoryEntry(userDn);), i am getting errors in uEntry properties and UserName is shown as null.

Answer (score 0):

As an MCSE, I do password resets many times a day so I can tell you something about this.

There are basically two operations you can perform with an Active Directory password - a change, and a reset. Changing a password requires that you know the current password on an account, but resetting a password does not require you to know the current password on an account, so in a way, in order to change a user's password without knowing the password, you really need to perform a password reset operation on the account.

By the way, i believe there are two seperate Active Directory extended rights that control each of these permissions, but I am not intimately familiar with them, as I am a delegated admin who is delegated thos abillity.

So, please keep in mind that any attempts to reset a user's password will fail if you don't have the reset password right granted to you on the target user account.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question that was asked. Keep in mind this is not a website for administrators - it's for programmers. Check out the accepted answer for some hints about what a 'correct' answer to this question was. Also, your links to that website seem a bit spammy; it has absolutely nothing to do with coding.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new library introduced in .net 3.5 called System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.  It simplifies user management stuff.

```
    public void ChangePassword(string dn, string newPassword)
    {
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, dn))
            {
                user.SetPassword(newPassword);
            }
        }
    }
```